# Scan QRCode using Unity ARKit plugin

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

Can anyone guide me on how to scan a QRCode using Unity3d ARKit plugin?

I'm able to scan it using WebCamTexture. Need to do it through ARKit so I can place an object over the QRCode.

Thanks.